# .htacces URL rewrite issue: rewrites the URL with the same variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my URLs from something like:

```
http://domain.com/edit.php?proname=abc
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/abc
```

This is my current rewrite code in .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ edit.php?proname=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ edit.php?proname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The code 'kinda' works. The problem is it rewrites all the 'edit' URL with the same variable.
So for example, I have a table with three projects and each project has an 'Edit' button.When I click on the 'Edit' button for Project 2 or 3, it refers me to the edit page of Project 1. All the edit links refers me to the edit page of the first project.

What may cause it?

SOLVED: Turns out there was a logic error in the PHP script. Thank you, Olaf!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The htaccess can be simplified, but looks correct so far. The problem must be with the `edit.php` script.

N.B.: You can reduce the two rules to just one rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ edit.php?proname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: You were right, turns out there was a logic error in the PHP script. Thank you!